# How can i capture an event in a component which is emitted from another component?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I want to capture the event in a component which is emitted event from another component.

I did the following code

**myservice.ts**

```
private _event = new EventEmitter<any>();

get event(): EventEmitter<any> {
  return this._event;
}
```

**mycomponent_2.ts**

```
this.myservice.event.emit(true);
```

**mycomponent_1.ts** - Added the below code in ngOnInit()

```
this.myservice.event.subscribe((value) =>  {
  console.log(value);
});
```

The expected console log not printed. Looks the event is not captured in the component_2

How can I solve this? Do I need to move the code to some other life cycle hook?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html) so that it emits the previously emitted value. The EventEmitter losses any values after they are emitted.

If the service tries to emit the value before the component is created, then the value will be lost unless you use one of the buffering subjects.

```
private _event = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

get event(): EventEmitter<any> {
  return this._event;
}
```

There is also the [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) which allows you to define a *default* value that is emitted before `next()` is called for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Subject**: A Subject is like an Observable, but can multicast to many Observers. Subjects are like EventEmitters: they maintain a registry of many listeners.

in **service**

```
   @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {

    private yourVariable: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


    public listenYourVariable() {
        return this.yourVariable.asObservable();

    }


    public yourVariableObserver(value : type) {
        this.yourVariable.next(value);
    }
```

You import in yours **components** where you want use it this service.

```
import{ YourService } from ...
```

In **component** you want write the data call:

```
this.yourService.yourVariableObserver(yourData);
```

while where you want read the data:

```
  this.yourService.listenYourVariable().subscribe(
        variable => {
          this.data = variable;
        }

)
```

Comment: EventEmitter is a Subject. They are extended from the Subject class.https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e0ad9ecda0b8a541b405d2ab35335b90ceb21fd1/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64

Comment: It is right, but Angular2 team has stated that they can change eventEmitter implementation, so it a good practice to use it only with @Output decorator, in this way user code will not be broken due to a its possible change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an event, read on. I created a repo and got this working by adding an @output to the event like so:

```
export class MyServiceService {
@Output() event = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor() {}
```

}

then to make sure there were no timing issues I created one button to add the listener in one component and another button to fire the event. Thus I think the main mistake is the lack of the @Output decorator.

Comment: After further review, you do not need the @Output(). However it appears ReplaySubject is my next learning adventure.

Answer (score 0):

One of the preferred choice is `BehaviorSubject`.
Here , a service can be used to share the data between the 2 component.

**It highly useful when the components are not related to each other.**

Ex: 
Service : StringService

```
private testString=new BehaviorSubject<string>("Test") //Default value can be passed
public stringValue=this.testString.asObservable();


  passStringChange(project:string){
    this.testString.next(project)
  }
```

Component 1:

```
str:string

clickHere(){
this.stringService.passStringChange(str)
}
```

Component 2:

```
stringObtained:string
this.stringService.stringValue.subscribe(message=>this.stringObtained=message)
```