# How to call value from a class to another in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to import variables which are from Items class, but I can't figure out how it should be done.
Heres an example of my code,

**item.ts:**

```
export class Item{
   itemName: string;
   id: sstring;
}
```

**user.ts**

```
import {Item} from './item'

export class Users{
   username: string;
   id: string;
}
```

The question is how can I get the value itemName inside the user.ts.

Comment: If these components are parent/child, you can use [@Input()](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Comment: Is the `ItemComponent` a child or `UsersComponent`?

Comment: A child of userItem.service becuase they share the same userItem.service, so they are both child of userItem.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look a lot like models. So you are defining the structure of what a user and item should look like with some typing restrictions. You could add an item to a user's model like so.

```
import {Item} from './item'

export class Users{
   username: string;
   id: string;
   item: Item;
}
```

This will type Users.item to your Item class. Just to clarify you would therefore have `itemName` under `user.item.itemName`

Comment: Thanks for this answer I can access objects, but for some reason when I output the itemName it's giving me an error of: undefined, where it should list the value

Comment: This is likely a problem with how you have instantiated your User or Item on the user. Maybe you could show us a bit of code around how you are using these models in a component? If you have a user model already made and want to add the item to it the following would work. `user.item = new Item('itemName', 'id')`.

Comment: No problem I figured it out and it worked, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not much clear, if you intend not like component.

```
import {Item} from './item';

 export class User {
      username:string;
      id: string;
      item: Item;
}
```

In this way you have in User objects of Item type.

Otherwise if Item and User are components, then depends by their relationship.
If they are child-parent relation you can use @Input to pass value:
In the Item HTML

```
<user-selector [itemName] = 'item'></user_selector>
```

in User ts;

```
@Input itemName: string;
```

If they are not relation between them, so you can use a service and use Subject to comunicate between them:
[How can i capture an event in a component which is emitted from another component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792696/how-can-i-capture-an-event-in-a-component-which-is-emitted-from-another-componen/59793186#59793186)

Comment: Thanks, next time I'll try to explain better!